# Fedora 20 Monitor Flickering /Tremble

Tags: fedora, monitors, atom

I used a LCD monitor with Fedora 10. No problem.
Then, I bought a new computer, Intel Atom (Packard Bell) and installed Fedora 20 KDE Plasma and attached the previous LCD monitor
Everything fine, except the monitor that now flickers (a steady tremble). This is annoying, especially when I use terminal with black background.
Anyone can help?